# Find file glob pattern or regex by name but allow for exact match at beginning and only certain characters at end

Tags: find, regular-expression, wildcards

I am trying to match some image files which share a basic name but have sizing information appended to the end with `find . -name 'Name*'` to match files such as:

```
Name.jpg
Name@2x.jpg
Name-180x101.jpg
Name-180x101@2x.jpg
```

However my glob pattern also matches:

```
NameLonger.jpg
NameLonger@2x.jpg
NameLonger-180x101.jpg
NameLonger-180x101@2x.jpg
```

The second group is undesired.

How can I adapt my `find` command to hit the first group but ignore the second? Is it possible with a glob pattern, or is a regex needed?

Note: For this case, the sizing information (-180x101) is always "-" then any number of numerical digits , then "x", then any number of numerical digits. If a file includes '@2x' it is always at the end.

Note: It must also hit on the plain file, e.g: `Name.jpg`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `zsh`, to be specific about the format of file names you want:

```
print -rC1 -- **/Name(-<->x<->|)(@<->x|).jpg(DN)
```

- `print -rC1`: `print` `r`aw on `1` `C`olumn
- `**/`: recursive globbing
- `(a|b)`: alternation, so `(x|)` is like ERE `(x)?`
- `<x-y>`: sequence of decimal digits representing integer numbers x to y, `<->` sequence of digits representing any number.
- `D`: `dotglob`: also look in hidden dirs like `find` does.
- `N`: `nullglob`: don't complain if there's no match and expand to nothing instead.

A GNU `find` equivalent (without the sorting of files and with `./` prefixed to each path):

```
LC_ALL=C find . -regextype posix-extended -regex \
  '.*/Name(-[0-9]+x[0-9]+)?(@[0-9]+x)?\.jpg'
```

(with BSD `find`, use `find -E .` instead of `find . -regextype posix-extended`)

With standard `find`, maybe:

```
find . -name '.*/Name[-@.]*'
```

Would be enough if all you need is exclude `NameLonger`.

The simple wildcard patterns have no equivalent for the `+`, `?` or `|` operators. It would be possible to do something equivalent with a number of `-name` and `! -name` ANDed and ORed together (like accept `Name-*x*.jpg`  but reject `Name-*[!0-9]*x*[!0-9]*.jpg`, `Name-x*`, `Name-*x.jpg`, etc) but that would be extremely cumbersome as you'd need hundreds of those to handle all case.

The GNU libc implementation of the `fnmatch()` function (as used by `find -name`) can be told to support some ksh88 extended glob operators (`FNM_EXTMATCH` flag) which bring regex equivalence (the `+(...)`, `?(...)`... also supported by `zsh -o kshglob` or `bash -O extglob`), but AFAIK, not even the GNU implementation of `find` can be told to use them.

POSIXly, you could resort to `awk` to refine the matching:

```
LC_ALL=C find . -name 'Name*' -exec awk '
  BEGIN {
    for (i = 1; i < ARGC; i++)
      if (ARGV[i] ~ "/Name(-[0-9]+x[0-9]+)?(@[0-9]+x)?\\.jpg$")
        print ARGV[i]
  }' {} +
```

(bearing in mind that it could fail if the paths of some files are too long to fit in a command line. Not all `find` implementations are able to find files of paths longer than `PATH_MAX` anyway).

Comment: `zsh` command was very useful and performed very well, but I needed this on a webserver where I am not able to change the shell.

I modified your GNU `find` example in the context of my needs by making the regex hit any file extension, and added a sub-directory in the tree to ignore:

`find ./path/to/files -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*/FileName(-[0-9]+x[0-9]+)?(@[0-9]+x)?\.[^.]+$' -not -path './path/to/files/skip/*'`

This worked very well to find duplicates in neighboring directories running across nearly 10k input files and covering 50GB of files.

Thank you.

Comment: @tlock, would be better as `find ./path/to/files -regextype posix-extended -path ./path/to/files/skip -prune -o -regex '.*/FileName(-[0-9]+x[0-9]+)?(@[0-9]+x)?\.[^/.]+$' -print` i.e. prune the paths you want to skip and make sure you're not including `/` in the run-away parts of your regexp.